# Java: Using the split function with multiple delimiters

Tags: java, regex, split

I would like to split a string based on two delimiters.

1. The first delimiter is a, space " " and
2. The second is a "."
3. However, the last sentence that ends with full stop should not be
   splitted.

For the given string:

```
Undersay    v.  To say by way of derogation or contradiction.
```

I would like the following output

```
Undersay

v.

To say by way of derogation or contradiction.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @santosh-patil I tried this initially String [] str = str1.split("(\" \")|(.)");

Comment: . Is anything in regex. You need to escape it to mean the actual .

Comment: @ Fildor I tried this solution. It does not produce the desired output

Comment: What happens to this input "abc def pqr" ? this should also split right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by this regex:

```
 (?=.*\.(?=.*\.))|(?<=\.)(?=.*\.)
```

Or as java string:

```
" (?=.*\\.(?=.*\\.))|(?<=\\.)(?=.*\\.)"
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVTQjy/8/)

Sample Java Code:

```
final String regex1 = " (?=.*\\.(?=.*\\.))|(?<=\\.)(?=.*\\.)"
final String string = "Undersay v.To say by way of derogation or contradiction.";

String[] result=string.split(regex1);

for(String s:result) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Will output:**

> Undersay
>
> v.
>
> To say by way of derogation or contradiction.

Comment: this solution produces the desired output. However, it removes the first "." in the string. That is not the behavior that I want.

Comment: How could I possible modify this regular expression so that it does not remove the first "." from the string?